# How can a person get help in learning Redis Online

Tags: database, redis, installation, in-memory-database, in-memory-data-grid

I have visited [Redis](https://redis.io/) official website and more other platforms for the tutorials but still I am unable to installation of Redis (in-memory data structure store).

The [README.md](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/README.md) file at Github is also failed to let me complete install and play with Redis.

I am a beginner to Redis and needs some specific and easy guidance in learning or installing it to system and play with it.

Comment: Please tell more information what error or message do you see. This will help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Redis University](https://university.redislabs.com/dashboard). It provides a Virtual Lab environment for each student. Courses are free. Of course, there are many other tutorials, videos, courses, and books available.

Installation on Windows is not recommended. You have a few options before having to install yourself, if you want just to play with it:

- [AWS ElastiCache for Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/) free for 12 months (cache.t2micro or cache.t3.micro Node, 750 h/month). AWS provides many [tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Tutorials.html) as well.
- [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://app.redislabs.com/#/essentials-pro-selection), you choose your favorite cloud for hosting, and it's free up to 30 MB. No CC required.
- [Redis docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis). You can run it with [docker desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) in Mac or Windows as well.

You can try the classic redis-cli to play with it. You can also try some GUI clients available, like [RDBTools](https://rdbtools.com/).

If you are trying to install and facing problems, then post a question with the specifics of what have you tried and what the error you are getting is.

Comment: Thanks @LeoMurillo its really worth.